# While clicking on enter,its not going to the immediate next Edit field in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my code:

```
uam.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

              public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                  switch (keyCode)
                  {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                      if(((EditText)findViewById(view.getId())) == ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.UamEditTextFm)))
                      {
                          Log.d("setOnKeyListener","Uam To port");
                        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.PortAdvFm)).requestFocus();

                      }
                      return true;
                    default:
                      break;
                  }
                }
                return false;
              }
            });

        port.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
              public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                  switch (keyCode)
                  {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                      if(((EditText)findViewById(view.getId())) == ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.PortAdvFm)))
                      {
                          Log.d("setOnKeyListener","Port To ConType");
                          ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ConTypeAdvFm)).requestFocus();
                      }
                      return true;
                    default:
                      break;
                  }
                }
                return false;
              }
            });

        connectType.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
              public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                  switch (keyCode)
                  {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                      if(((EditText)findViewById(view.getId())) == ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ConTypeAdvFm)))
                      {
                          Log.d("setOnKeyListener","ConType To saveBtn ");
                        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveAdvSettingofFm)).requestFocus();
                        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveAdvSettingofFm)).performClick();
                      }
                      return true;
                    default:
                      break;
                  }
                }
                return false;
              }
            });
```

**When clicking Enter it not focus on `port`,but focus goes to the `connectType` field.**
Please help me out.
Xml file is:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:text="UAM:" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/UamEditTextFm" android:singleLine="true" android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoText="true" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:text="Port:" />

        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/PortAdvFm" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:text="ConType:" />

        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/ConTypeAdvFm" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/SaveAdvSettingofFm" android:text="Save"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```

Comment: add this `((EditText) findViewById(R.id.PortAdvFm)).setFocusable(true);
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.PortAdvFm)).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`

Comment: i have allready used this code,but not working.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your edit text xml tag

```
 android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

Comment: you want that as you press enter the edit text will move to nex control ??

Comment: could you please give your xml

Comment: i have added the xml.Plz go through it.

Comment: i have 3 edit text and at bottom place there is a button.when clicking on enter it should goes to 2nd edit text,it is going to 2nd edit field but not focusing on it,it is just going to 3rd edit text via second.

Comment: ya okay i m just checking your xml